# How can we edit any input field in angularjs by using edit button in bootsrap?

Tags: angularjs

Iam working with angularjs ecommerce project.Here I have to edit the input field of showing price,whenever I have required in the view,using the bootstrap edit button.How can I write the code for editing any field in angularjs?
Actually I have to show the price of a product in one html page.There edit button will be present and whenever I have clicked that button,I have to go to another page for editing the price field and this has to be reflected to first html page.I have strucked at writing the code for this whole process.

Comment: share your code to let people help you

Comment: Can you add some code snippet for the better understanding of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-simple) plugin, it will give your editable textbox, grid, datetime etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, your finding difficult to handle global variables. There are two way you can Define global variables in angularjs as i know.

- using a `$rootScope` - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope

Though u can easily use `$rootScope` just by injecting them in the `controller` and change values, but they have problems. `$rootScope` is the parent of all scopes, so values defined in rootscope basically is visible in all templates you define and use, where you have less control over the `$rootScope` attributes and its values. For more infor Read [this](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

- using a service http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

This would be ideal in your scenario because Services are singletons. This means that you can inject it to any controller and expose their values within the controller's scope only. According to that you have more control over it. Below fiddle will give an example of using service.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
    name: 'your name'
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, UserService) {
  $scope.name = UserService.name;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```